# Passing a value from a table to a placeholder Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to pass data from a datatable (data is a string)

```
<td>{{ object.name }}</td>
```

to a modal placeholder

```
<input
  v-model="editEquipName"
  type="text"
  :placeholder="''"
  class="form-control w-300px"
>
```

`v-model` is  for later transfer of data to the backend.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a property from the `object` variable to fill the `<td>`, why just not to use the same variable into the placeholder?

```js
<td>{{ object.name }}</td>
```

```js
<input
  v-model="editEquipName"
  type="text"
  :placeholder="object.name"
  class="form-control w-300px"
>
```

Or if the modal is another component, you could try to pass as a prop:

```js
<td>{{ object.name }}</td>

<Modal :name="object.name" />
```

modal.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="modal">
    <input
      v-model="editEquipName"
      type="text"
      :placeholder="name"
      class="form-control w-300px"
    >
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Modal",
  props: {
    name: string
  }
};
</script>
```